# Picasso is loading images again in new Activity causing improper Shared Transition Animation in the App

Tags: android, image, animation, caching, picasso

I have an activity 1 which has a recycler view containing list of around 50 images each around 20-40 kb in size which is being fetched using picasso library.
Now I have Implemented android shared transition on the images when user clicks on an image.
The problem is that when the user clicks on an image that is already loaded in activity A , the image loads again in activity B due to which the shared transition occurrs on activity B's placeholder image only.
Whereas, everything works fine the second time the same image is clicked.
I cant understand why this is happening. Since Picasso uses caching, so the image should be available anytime, specially when it is on the screen.

The Picasso Part I have used in Activity A and B are as follows:

Activity A's recycler view adapter:

```
     @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.publisher_name.setText(feedsList.get(position).getPublisher_display_name());
    holder.feed_time_span.setText(feedsList.get(position).getFeedtime());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(feedsList.get(position).getPublisher__pic()).tag("publisher_pic")
            .into(holder.publisher_pic);

    holder.feed_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedsList.get(position).getFeed_title()));
    holder.feed_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedsList.get(position).getFeed_description()));

    Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
            .load(feedsList.get(position).getFeed_image_url()).fit()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loader2).tag("feed_pic")
            .into(holder.feed_pic);

    Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    }
```

Activity B's onCreate:

```
      private void showData() {
    SourceSemiBoldTextView title = (SourceSemiBoldTextView) findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blog_pic);
    title.setText(articledata.get("articletitle"));

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(articledata.get("articleimageurl")).fetch();
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(articledata.get("articleimageurl"))
            .error(R.drawable.loader2)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loader2).fit().noFade()
            .into(image);

    Picasso.with(this).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    }
```

Any Help Will be Highly Appreciated. Please Let me Know if I need need to add anything else for clearer understanding

Answer (score 3):

I just found out what I was doing wrong. I just removed the .fit() from both the activities and everything seems to work fine now.